# How to retrive Blob pdf file from MySql database using java

Tags: java, netbeans

Hello guys I need help. I have code below which saves the pdf file into mysql database it works perfectly, but i don't know how to retrieve the pdf file into my pc. Any idea how to do it? Thanks

```
try{  
//connection string

File pdfFile = new File ("d:\\modularing.pdf");

byte[] pdfData = new byte[(int) pdfFile.length()];

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(pdfFile));

dis.readFully(pdfData);  // read from file into byte[] array

dis.close();

PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO filetable (" + "ID, " + 

"PDF_file " + ") VALUES (?,?)");

ps.setString(1, "newpdffile");

ps.setBytes(2, pdfData);  // byte[] array

ps.executeUpdate();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You should use [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) is the key  for reading blobs, try search for the APIs to read the blob pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the API for Blob, in particular the getBinaryStream() method, which retrieves an InputStream